# how to filter data table from specific date to specific date using bindingsource in c# ?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

```
 tennisBindingSource.Filter = "Booking_Date <= '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + 
"# Booking_Date > #" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "#";
```

I Get the error cannot perform '>=' operation on system.datetime and system.string

Comment: is `Booking_Date` is of type datetime?

Comment: @Rahul no it's string , and on sql its date type

Answer (score 0):

Error is cause your `Booking_Date` is of type `datetime` and you are trying to compare with string. Rather change your code to be like below. Don't convert it to `ToShortDateString()`. `dateTimePicker1.Value` returns a `DateTime` instance.

```
tennisBindingSource.Filter = "Booking_Date <= " + dateTimePicker1.Value
```